# Как в Java обрабатывать введенное в консоль в реальном времени, то есть прямо во время ввода и выбрасывать исключение, если ввод неверный?

Tags: java, исключения, ввод, поток-ввода

Мне нужно реализовать ввод данных в Java таким образом, что исключение будет выбрасываться даже без нажатия Enter для конца ввода, то есть моментально. Пытался что-то искать на эту тему, все тщетно, не понимаю, как можно добиться этого

Comment: Исключения `InputMismatchException` так и выбрасываются, если к примеру считываются целые числа при помощи `scanner.nextInt()`, а вводятся нецелочисленные данные

Comment: А если мне нужно проверять длину слова при вводе, то есть, я не пользователь при попытке ввести слово длиной больше чем 10, будет получать исключение

Comment: аналогично, есть методы [`Scanner::hasNext(String pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext-java.lang.String-) и [`Scanner::next(String pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next-java.lang.String-), выбрасывающие исключения, если введенное строковое значение не соответствует заданному шаблону

Comment: @NowhereMan это будет работать без окончания ввода, то есть одновременно с попыткой ввода будет выбрасываться exception?

Comment: @stukenvitalii, ввод будет обрабатываться только после ввода строки целиком.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, необязательно -- сканер может обрабатывать токены до ввода строки целиком

Comment: @NowhereMan, не может. Консоль не отдаст ввод в программу до нажатия `Enter`. Так работает строчный редактор консоли (пока вы можете редактировать строку её не показывают программе). Вы правы в случае ввода из файла, но не из консоли.

Comment: ТС ищет возможность посимвольного ввода из консоли. Насколько я знаю, в стандартной Java это не возможно, но есть библиотеки, которые зависят от операционной системы и позволяют делать с консолью всё что может с нею делать `ncurses`.

Comment: ввод будет проверяться после появления первого разделителя, по умолчанию разделителями являются пробельные символы в том числе и перевод строки (Enter).

Comment: @NowhereMan не работает такая проверка, мне нужно, чтобы все проверялось сразу без нажатия Enter

Comment: Консоль так не работает, о чем вам написали выше.

Comment: Похоже, вы хотите обрабатывать события нажатий на клавишах, что может выполняться только в графическом интерфейсе (Swing).  А в консоли должен быть введен некий разделитель, после которого может быть проанализирован введенный токен.

Answer (score 0):

Класс Scanner может обрабатывать значения в потоке ввода и проверять наличие соответствующих токенов *до того*, как будет введена строка целиком.

Например, для ввода "слова" длиной не более 10 символов можно применить код:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String name = sc.next("\\S{1,10}"); // От 1 до 10 непробельных символов
```

При вводе *любого пробела* после ввода слишком длинного слова будет выброщено исключение:

```
123451234512 Exception in thread "main" 1java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1525)
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:11)
```